# How to run Spring LoadTimeWeaving for JPA Repository

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, eclipselink, load-time-weaving

I am trying to add Repository support to an Eclipselink JPA Spring project.  Eclipselink requires LoadTimeWeaving - even though that's not absolutely true I'd later like to get Aspects working as well.

The production application runs under Tomcat, and I might be done by now if I had gone along and not tried to create JUnits.  I have a feeling that maybe what I really have is an Eciplse (STS 3.4) problem since it seems to be ignoring my alternate class loader.  But it seems so basic that this must work, and that I'm doing something wrong.

I am using exclusively Annotations and Java configuration.  The relevant code below.

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@Profile("data")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.xxx.ieexb.repository",transactionManagerRef="transactionManager",entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory")
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.xxx.ieexb.jpa"
                    ,"com.xxx.ieexb.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@ImportResource("classpath:/properties-config.xml")
public class IeexbDataContextConfig {
@Value("#{ieexbProperties['com.xxx.ieexb.dataSource.Url']}")
public String dataSourceUrl;
@Value("#{ieexbProperties['com.xxx.ieexb.dataSource.Username']}")
public String dataSourceUsername;
@Value("#{ieexbProperties['com.xxx.ieexb.dataSource.Password']}")
public String dataSourcePassword;
@Value("#{ieexbProperties['com.xxx.ieexb.persistenceUnitName']}")
public String persistenceUnitName;

@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean()
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource");
    dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean()
EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter() {
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform");
    return eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean()
EclipseLinkJpaDialect jpaDialect() {
    EclipseLinkJpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
    return jpaDialect;
}

@Bean()
public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //TODO Does this @Configuration do away with need for persistence.xml?
    //emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:persistence.xml");
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emf.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver());
    emf.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(eclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
    //emf.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider());
    return emf;
}

@Bean()
public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
    LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver();
    return loadTimeWeaver;
}
}
```

The dead simple Entity (with some of the truly boring columns removed):

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name="PENDING_QUEUE"
, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="IEEXB_ID,QUEUE_TIMESTAMP")
)
public class PendingQueue implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
    @AttributeOverride(name="ieexbId", column=@Column(name="IEEXB_ID", nullable=false) ),
    @AttributeOverride(name="queueTimestamp", column=@Column(name="QUEUE_TIMESTAMP", nullable=false) ) } )
private PendingQueueId id;
@Column(name="IE_USER", nullable=false, length=21)
private String ieUser;
@Column(name="COMMAND_TYPE", nullable=false, length=3)
private String commandType;


public PendingQueue() {
    ;
}

public PendingQueue(PendingQueueId id, String ieUser, String commandType) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.ieUser = ieUser;
    this.commandType = commandType;
}

public PendingQueueId getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(PendingQueueId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIeUser() {
    return ieUser;
}

public void setIeUser(String ieUser) {
    this.ieUser = ieUser;
}

public String getCommandType() {
    return commandType;
}

public void setCommandType(String commandType) {
    this.commandType = commandType;
}
....
}
```

The Repository of course:

```
@Repository
public interface PendingQueueRepository extends CrudRepository<PendingQueue, PendingQueueId> {
List<PendingQueue> findByIeUser(String ieUser);
}
```

And finally the JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"data"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IeexbDataContextConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TestPendingQueue {
@Autowired
PendingQueueRepository pendingQueueRepository;

@Test
public void testFindByIeUser() {
    List<PendingQueue> results = pendingQueueRepository.findByIeUser("JPA.XXX.BOB1");
    System.out.println("Found Items:" + results.size());
    System.out.println("First item is:" + results.get(0));


}
}
```

I am trying to run the JUnit with this VM ARG:
-javaagent:C:\Users\Terry\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-agent\2.5.6.SEC03\spring-agent-2.5.6.SEC03.jar

I also tried adding the AspectJ weaver, but it didn't help
-javaagent:C:\Users\Terry\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.0\aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar

I have not tried the Spring Tomcat weaver but that doesn't seem like the right direction. I've read people then had problems with JUnit finding class files.

Without pasting in the rather huge stack trace it all boils down to this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver
 com.xxx.ieexb.config.IeexbDataContextConfig.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
```

Which is of course true.  That classloader doesn't support weaving.  But I have tried very very hard to not use that loader.  Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and adding the following VM args for unit tests works for me:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar
```

Comment: I had actually been using spring-instrument but read somewhere to use spring-agent instead.  Unfortunately neither works. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was that in the @Configuration class I included a definition for a LoadTimeWeaver bean.  I also set that value inside the EntityManagerFactory constructor.  By removing that I no longer get the runtime error during spring container startup.

Looking at the Spring console it says my Entity Beans were transformed (woven) so perhaps Lazy loading would still work - I don't have any DB associations to try it on in this particular project.

One other note is not only is **persistence.xml NOT required** it is not allowed.  Eclipselink was hunting down another copy of persistence.xml I didn't know about and that was causing the Entity backing my Repository to not get discovered.

But right now I believe the example I've posted (minus the loadTimeWeaving bean) is, remarkably, one of the best, or at least most complete, examples out there - who'd have expected that!

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't get the above to work. amazon aws doesn't let me put the instrumentation jar in tomcat/lib folder so i could not use -javaagent approach (believe me i tried!). i had to switch to [eclipselink static weaving](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving)

it's not too hard, a persistence.xml file is required but if you're already using annotated configuration it can be as short as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ADD_NAME_HERE">
        <!--this is necessary for the eclipselink static weaving maven plugin-->
        <!--this setting auto-detects entities in the project-->
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

but note that it MUST be in your project that contains the entity classes. i made the mistake of dropping the persistence.xml file and the maven plugin in the pom.xml file into my website project not my domain project.

Answer (score 0):

If one needs to set -javaagent by maven, it can do it like this:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${org.springframework.version}/spring-instrument-${org.springframework.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

(just set property for ${org.springframework.version} or replace for corresponding version)
This way it's associated with your project, and not with your jvm or webserver